# Extract and display user infromation on an automatically created page

Tags: php, functions, theme-development

Is there a way to get the block of code below to extract a list of given user information as it creates the page for the new user. It creates new page for new user as supposed but I'd like it to alos extract and display some information from the user profile.

```
function my_create_page($user_id){
    $the_user = get_userdata($user_id);
    $new_user_name = $the_user->user_login;
    $my_post = array();
    $my_post['post_title'] = $new_user_name;
    $my_post['post_type'] = 'page';
    $my_post['post_content'] = '';
    $my_post['post_status'] = 'publish';
    $my_post['post_theme'] = 'user-profile';
    wp_insert_post( $my_post );
}
add_action('user_register', 'my_create_page');
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to grab the information you're after from $the_user.

If you use:

```
$my_post['post_content'] = print_r($the_user,true);
```

you should be able to see all the available user information in the page. Once you know exactly what you want, you can echo it out nicely with something like:

```
$my_post['post_content'] = "Username: ".$the_user->user_login."<br />Roles:".$the_user->roles;
```

If that's not quite what you were after let me know!

Comment: Can it be incopreated with what I already have?

Comment: Yes. Simply replace the existing line starting with $my_post['post_content'] in your code, with the first code snippet I posted above. If you then create a new user and see what the page looks like, you can then instead use the second code snippet I posted in order to only show the details you want to show. Once you know what user details are available from the first snippet, feel free to let me know exactly which user details you want to print out and I can rewrite that second snippet for you.

Comment: Hi Dz1, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it helped you out! Let me know if you need any more guidance.

Comment: Working on this  now. WIl let you know hot it goes.

Comment: How did you go with this @Dz1?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem can be accomplished with a page template, but first we need to fix your previews code

```
<?php
/**/
function add_user_page($user_id){
    $user = get_userdata($user_id);
    $role_with_page = "subscriber";
    if( reset($user->roles) != $role_with_page ) return; //Exit if user role doesn't allows ownership of page
    $post_type = 'page'; /// I would prefer a custom post type like 'user_upages'
    global $wpdb;
    $where = get_posts_by_author_sql( $post_type, true, $user_id );
    if( $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts $where" ) >= 1 ) return; // Exit if the user already have a page
    $title = $user->user_login;
    $template = 'user-profile.php'; // if the post type where a CPT you could create just the file single-$posttype.php
    $user_page = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_type'     => $post_type,
        'post_content'  => '', // leave empty the post content so the user can edit this just in case than you will enable this option...
        'post_author'   => $user_id,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_theme'    => 'user-profile', // ???? Are you talkin about page_template ?
        'page_template' => $template
        );
    if( $post_id = wp_insert_post( $user_page ) ){
        if( $post_type == 'page' ) update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_page_template',  $template );
        __update_post_meta( $post_id, 'foobar', 'some value' ); // Save all the data you need as post_meta
        __update_post_meta( $post_id, 'user_owner', $user_id ); // This is just in case you dont want to give ownership (post_author) to the user
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_owns_unique_page', $post_id ); // Store the page owned by this user
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'some_random_stuff', rand( 0,10 ) ); // Store the page owned by this user
    }
    //do_action('acf/save_post' , $post_id); /* Uncomment this if you use ACF (than you should) ;) */
    return $post_id;
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'add_user_page' );
add_action( 'set_user_role', 'add_user_page' );

?>
```

You should leave the post_content as it is because this is static data that will not retrieve the user data.
If you really want to update the post_content then you would just add a shortcode (you should write the shortcode in your functions.php).
Ex.

```
'post_content'  => "[show_user_data id='{$user_id}']",
```

Then if you want to use the page_template then your user-profile.php should like something like :

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: User profile page
 * Description: A Page Template for users.
 */

get_header();

while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();
    $user_id = get_the_author_meta( "ID" ); // or get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'user_owner', true );
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $user_name = $user->first_name." ".$user->last_name;
    $some_random_stuff = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'some_random_stuff', $single ); 
    $foobar = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , 'foobar', true );
    ?>
    <ul>
        <li><?php echo $user_name ?></li>
        <li><?php echo $some_random_stuff ?></li>
        <li><?php echo $foobar ?></li>
        <li><?php the_content(); ?></li>
    </ul>
    <?php
endwhile;
get_footer();
?>
```

You can read this : 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

Hope this helps.